# Fetching data with fetch from backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, mern

i am working on a prject in which i have data being sent to me from

"http://localhost:5000/api/chat/"

i.e. local host 5000

Now i want to fetch it and show it in my react project which is on localhost 3000.

I am using fetch method to get the data like

```
fetch("/api/chat").then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>console.log(data));
```

but it is showing the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

//Note:

api/chat is giving me json data, there is no problem in it

also i tried it, using "proxy": "https:127.0.0.1:5000" in pakage.json but still getting this error

//

Please tell me the correct way to get it

Comment: I think fetch work only on the browser and frontend not on nodejs, they have just introduce it lately to node js, not sure youre using it the right way on node, can you show the whole code? but it's better to use axios

Answer (score 0):

You're `fetch()` is returning HTML and you're trying to parse it as JSON.  Can't do that (results in the error you get).

If you want the HTML, then use `.text()` instead of `.json()`.

If you want JSON, then you need a different endpoint or different headers to that endpoint that causes it to provide JSON back to you.